# open dynamically fullcalendar in a section of my web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar

I hope to find solution here.

I have a PHP page (calendar.php) who work's fine (I use Fullcalendar). When I call http://localhost/calendar.php everything works well.

I have a main page (index.php) with a nav, a section and a footer.

In the index.php, I want to use JS to open the page calendar.php into the  (see code below).
When I call http://localhost/index.php and I click on the item menu "Accueil", the Js call the page (calendar.php) but nothing appears in the ID section and I have no error in the console.

If I change the link to open an other HTML test page (for example test.html) It works. If I use an other php test page (for example test.php) It works also.

I don't find why the calendar page (calendar.php) didn't open in my section ???

This is the index.php code :

```
    <title>Test</title>
     <link href='<?=$dir;?>style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
     <script src='<?=$dir;?>packages/jquery/jquery.js'></script>    
     <script src='<?=$dir;?>main.js'></script>

    <header>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>Carnets de voyage</h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="./calendar.php" id="Zmenu1">Accueil</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="<?=$dir;?>calendar/index.php" id="Zmenu1">Accueil</a></li> -->
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Accueil</h1>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And this is the JS code (main.js):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr('href')

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#menu li a').click(function(event){
       var url = $(this).attr('href');
       $('#content').load(url + "#content");
       //$('#content').load("/calendar/index.php");
       event.preventDefault();
     });
   });
```

Does somebody can help me to understand why the calendar.php page doesn't appears ?

Thanks a lot.

(Sorry for my poor english).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need to see calendar.php's code as well.

Comment: This is the example source of the calendar.php's code : https://dcblog.dev/jquery-fullcalender-with-php-and-mysql

Comment: If you use `.load` (or any other AJAX function) to load content which contains Javascript `<script>` blocks, usually that Javascript does not get executed. It's a security feature, generally. So the script which loads your calendar won't be executed.

Comment: P.S. why have you got `jQuery(document).ready` twice in your code? That isn't necessary.

Comment: Adyson, I have only 1 jQuery(document).ready in my code. It's an error in copy/paste.

Comment: You said : "If you use .load (or any other AJAX function) to load content which contains Javascript <script> blocks, usually that Javascript does not get executed. It's a security feature, generally. So the script which loads your calendar won't be executed.". I understand but how to open this page in section without this ?  I must open my calendar in other page ? REGARDS

Comment: `how to open this page in section`...you could have the necessary JS already in your main page, or load the necessary JS script after you've loaded the HTML.